# Azure Synapse SQL Serverless, how to create external table from CSV with fields longer than 8Kb?

Tags: sql, azure, csv, serverless, azure-synapse

I have a CSV with more than 500 fields, hosted on an Azure storage account; however I just need a couple of columns, which may contain values longer than 8Kbytes. For this reason, I started by writing a simple query in Azure Synapse SQL Serverless like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 C1, C2 FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://mysa.blob.core.windows.net/my_file.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

It fails with the error "**String or binary data would be truncated while reading column of type 'VARCHAR'**". But it does not JUST report this warning, it does not return *ANY* rows because of this warning.
So, a simple solution is to disable warnings; of course that value is truncacted to 8Kb, but the query doesn't fail this way:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'https://mysa.blob.core.windows.net/my_file.csv',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
   AS [result] 

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Now I need some help to get the final target, which is to build an EXTERNAL TABLE, rather than just a SELECT, leaving the CSV where it is (in other words: I don't want to create a materialized view or a CETAS or a SELECT INTO which would duplicate data).

If I run it this way:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_CET (
    C1 NVARCHAR(8000),
    C2 NVARCHAR(8000)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'my_file.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = [my_data_source],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat]
    )
```

, it seems working because it successfully creates an external table, however if I try to read it, I get the error ***"External table my_CET is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process.***".
If I try setting ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, it tells me "***The option 'ANSI_WARNINGS' must be turned ON to execute requests referencing external tables.***".
As said I don't need all the 500 fields hosted in the CSV but just a couple of them, including the one which I should truncate data to 8KB as I did in the above example.

If I use a CSV file where no field is larger than 8KB, the external table creation works correctly, but I couldn't manage to make it work when some values are longer than 8Kb.

Answer (score 0):

I think when creating an external table from a csv you have to bring in all the columns.  I am sure someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Depending on what you want to do, you could create a view from the external table using a select query. e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW my_CET_Vw
AS
SELECT C1,
    C2
FROM my_CET
```